# How to make sure the Cookie is set before a new request is made?

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-headers, httprequest

I have an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091828/how-to-dispatch-2-subsequent-requests-without-a-cookie-to-the-same-jboss-node) that should be fixed on the server side, but a quick workaround on the client side would be acceptable.

I need to make a JS call after the page is loaded and the **http-only secure cookie** is already set. I'm using [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) event to call [window.location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.replace), but even though the page is loaded with the [SET-COOKIE](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) HTTP response header, the new request doesn't send the cookie.

**How to make sure the Cookie is set before a new request is made?**

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that works for Chrome, FF and IE8+ is to use a [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) inside the window.onload event handler. I'm looking for a better solution and an explanation, though...

Thanks,

Comment: have you confirm you solution is ok? the cookie is not always contain in the request.

Comment: @tank , I don't have access to this code anymore. Can you try it?

Comment: it worked only cookie set before a new request. a request has send out while onload exec. So, request will not contain the cookie you set after you request.