# How to dispatch 2 subsequent requests without a cookie to the same JBoss node?

Tags: tomcat, cookies, jboss, load-balancing, jsessionid

How to dispatch 2 subsequent requests without a cookie from the same client to the same `JBoss` node?

I have a multi-node setup with `Apache`, `JBoss7` (with `load balancing`, `sticky session` and `SSO`) and `Tomcat`. Here is the scenario:

1. User enters **https:///myapp** on the browser
2. Load balancer dispatches it to *node1*, on the **myapp.ear** file.
3. Since there is no authentication yet, **myapp** loads the unprotected `client_redirect.jsp` resource, which creates a `JSESSIONID` and returns to the client. The HTTP Response has the [header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=1234_.node1; Path=/myapp`
4. The "empty" page below* is loaded on the browser; the `onload` event handler changes the URL to  **https:///home/?app=myapp** and another request is sent. HOWEVER, [IT DOES NOT CONTAIN THE JSESSIONID cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091210/how-to-make-sure-the-cookie-is-set-before-a-new-request-is-made/)
5. server receives the 2nd request and, due to round-robin policy, dispatches it to *node2*, on **main.ear** file
6. **main** loads the unprotected `login.jsp` resource, which creates another `JSESSIONID` and returns to the client. The HTTP Response has the SET-COOKIE header as `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=5678_.node2; Path=/`
7. Login page is loaded, but now we have 2 JSESSIONID COOKIES on the browser, pointing to *different nodes*, which will lead to `SSO` issues after login, when we redirect to `https://<ip>/myapp` again

* "Empty" client_redirect page:

```
    <html>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            window.onload = function() { 
                window.location.replace('../../home/?app=myapp');    
            }
        </script> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution a friend suggested:

We don't need 2 `JSESSIONID` cookies, so we shouldn't create them in the 1st place. **myapp** should setup the `web.xml` file as follow, so both **main** and **myapp** can share the same session.

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Related links:

- [Session cookie path in JBoss 6](https://community.jboss.org/thread/170235?tstart=0)
- [Sharing session data between contexts in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436736/sharing-session-data-between-contexts-in-tomcat)